# Is infinity part of the boundary of R^n?

Tags: general-topology, infinity

I am having a set $S=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | x\in(-1,1), y\in(0,\infty) \} $. Does $\bar S$\S include the set of points for which $y\to\infty$; figuratively speaking, does it include the "boundary" at infinity?

Thanks for explanations!

Comment: Talking about a closure $\overline S$ presupposes an ambient topological space in which the closure is taken. If this space is $\Bbb R^2$, then the answer is "no".

Comment: As an easier example you may consider $(0,\infty)\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ the closure of this set does not contain infinity simply because $\infty\not\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally it doesn't. The overall space you are considering does not contain infinity either as a point itself. Normally for you to have infinity you would do a one point compactification of your space, very similar to the extended complex plane.